# iPhone SDK - Google TTS and encoding

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech

I am developing a text-to-speech iphone app that support multi-languages.

Here is my request URL

```
requestUrlStr = @"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello";
```

for english the above url has no problem

but for Chinese

```
requestUrlStr = @"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-TW&q=你好";
```

I know the above url will give 'Bad URL', so I used follow method to encode the string into `UTF-8`

```
requestUrlStr = [requestUrlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It will become

```
http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-CN&q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD
```

Then the Google TTS cannot recognize this Chinese text.

Comment: there seems to be some referrer restrictions... may be that is the problem.. and not the URL : http://jalam1001.posterous.com/google-text-to-speech-tts-weston-ruter-sent-u

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to pretend to be a User-Agent other than the default (appName, etc) in your NSURLRequest. Try this (I use Greek language) ...

```
NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=el&q=Καλημέρα" 
                                   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];

[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];


NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];



[data writeToFile:@"/var/tmp/tts.mp3" atomically:YES];
```

**UPDATE 2017**

Since our favorite companies enjoy to update and deprecate things, here is the above example as it should be now...

```
NSString* text = @"καλημέρα";
NSString* lang = @"el";

NSString* sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=%@&tl=%@&client=tw-ob", text, lang];
sUrl = [sUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:sUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
                                                      delegate:nil
                                                 delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                [data writeToFile:@"/var/tmp/tts.mp3" atomically:YES];
            }
  ] resume];
```

The `...delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` can be omitted.

Comment: It works perfectly. I dun know how many times I have to say thankyou to you. You really helped my problem alot. You are rock!!

Comment: I have a similar problem on android and haven't gotten any answers. what exactly are you doing here?

Comment: Have you tried to make the request through a browser? Did google returned the mp3 ?