# How to change Language in Google TTS API in iOS?

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I am using Google Text To Speech Services in iOS.

I am ok in English TTS with following codes.

```
NSString *queryTTS = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSString *linkTTS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%@",queryTTS];

NSData *dataTTS = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkTTS]];

_googlePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dataTTS error:nil]; 
[_googlePlayer play];
```

So i changed url address to speech thailand TTS like following link.

```
NSString *queryTTS = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSString *linkTTS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=th&q=%@",queryTTS];

NSData *dataTTS = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkTTS]];

_googlePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dataTTS error:nil]; 
[_googlePlayer play];
```

After I changed that link into `"th"` , that google TTS services not speech my thai text.

Am I wrong in my codes?

Or If no , how can I change languages in Google Text To Speech API?

Thanks you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say thanks.  I was looking for how to use the API on iPhone and this helped.  Also, I tried changing the language to Thai and had no problem.

*** ** UPDATE ** ***

Sorry, I was not able to get it work.  I didn't have any Thai text, so I just used English and it spelled the word out.  I assumed that meant it was working.  However, when I changed to Korean and Chinese using proper words I was not able to hear anything.  English, French, German and Italian all worked, however.

I was able to fix this by adding the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[linkTTS stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *dataTTS = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

The problem in my case (and probably yours) was that there were international characters in the URL.  That caused [NSURL URLWithString] to return nil.

That will work in the simulator, and to get the rest of the way, check out this thread:

[iPhone SDK - Google TTS and encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923974/iphone-sdk-google-tts-and-encoding)

Basically, you have to change your user agent to something else, like "Mozilla/5.0".