# Using google Text-To-Speech (TTS) API on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, text-to-speech, google-translate

I'm using the API with this code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mp3"];

NSString *text = textToTranslate; //@"You are one chromosome away from being a potato.";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%@",text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] ;
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

SystemSoundID soundID;
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url2, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

Which works but only on short sentences (less than 10 words approx.)
What am I doing wrong? How can I solve that or separate into few texts without reducing the speech quality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923974/iphone-sdk-google-tts-and-encoding

Comment: I'm familiar with that answer but still it's limited to 100 characters. How do I get over that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google TTS  limited to **100 characters**.

So you should **split-up your long sentence in to small 100  character chunks** and pass it to the Google TTS method.

**You can achieve this through implementing below steps.**

1. Split-up your long sentence in to small 100  character chunks.
2. Call  Google TTS with first split 100 character string.
3. Play it using Google TTS  & AVAudioPlayer
4. Implement  AVAudioPlayer audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate .
5. In that delegate, call  Google TTS with second split 100 character string.
6. Call the process recursively until reach the last character.

Here is my **[Google-TTS-Library-For-iOS](https://github.com/shamsudheen/Google-TTS-Library-For-iOS)** library that I created for you :)

Comment: This really helps but still sentences are cut by characters and not by words (easy to fix), Main problem is there is a big quiet between the two 100 chars sentences (maybe because the second request is made only after finish playing and not before...).

Comment: nope.. what you need to achieve? do you need source code? find here https://github.com/marceloqueiroz/GoogleTTSAPI

Comment: @Idan did you find a fix for the "pause/quiet" between 100-char blocks?

Comment: @Crashalot It was a long time ago so I think all this should be re-evaluate. At that time I just used another service provider for TTS.

Answer (score 2):

Google TTS is limited to 100 characters.

I recently created a lib that helped a lot with that problem. 
There are some improvements to be made, but please free to use it.
[GoogleTTSAPI](https://github.com/marceloqueiroz/GoogleTTSAPI)

Comment: I'll try this one because you provide the source code. Thanks

Comment: thanks for sharing! quick question: does this solve the pause that occurs between 100-character utterances, i.e., if you break a 500-char post into 5 chunks, will the 5 chunks be smoothly linked together or will there be noticeable gaps between chunks?